# To Add IP address in Azure Analysis Service Firewall Using scripting

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I want to add the list of IP's to the Azure Analysis Service(not sql account).
what I did:

```
$subscriptionId="xx"
$tenantid="xx"
$clientid="xx" #appid
$clientKey = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "whitelisting"
$password = $clientKey.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$ResourceGroupName="xx"
$ServerName="xx"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential

$rule1 = New-AzureRmAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName rule1 -RangeStart x.x.x.x -RangeEnd x.x.x.x

$rule2 = New-AzureRmAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName rule2 -RangeStart x.x.x.x -RangeEnd x.x.x.x

$config = New-AzureRmAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig -EnablePowerBIService -FirewallRule $rule1,$rule2
Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -FirewallConfig $config
```

Is this the correct approach?
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the issue ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: Hi Elikill58, When I run the Script the existing IP's are getting deleted. How can I append  my IP's to the Existing ones?